# Removing websites from notification centre - macOS 14

Tags: macos, safari, notifications, settings, sonoma

There are quite a few websites listed System Preferences -> Notifications that I can't remove.

The thing is, they don't appear in Safari-> Websites -> Notifications either so I can't delete them there.

I've tried deleting the folder `db2` from `com.apple.notificationcenter` but the entries still persist in notification centre even after a restart.

How can I remove website entries from the Notification Centre if they don’t appear in safari preferences?